# How do I tell a submenu to be visible when its parents or containing links are active?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a menu in HTML and it looks like this:

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Our Service</li>
         <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Everything is in shape via CSS except one thing: to get the submenu to appear when its parent list-item's link points to the same address as the current page address.

I know this is possible somehow. But I really am the greatest noob with JavaScript or jQuery or PHP (I think the last two mean the same thing right?).

I tried copying and pasting code pieces like "OnClick=..." and one that was like "" or also one I found that contained "GetElenentbyTagName" (which almost worked...) but besides that I had no real clue about where to put them even. They just didn't work properly or not at all. I had a full done code piece but when I pasted it in and replaced some tag names it all got got marked red and my head is burning after trying to get it to work for the entire day.

I think this is possible because I have seen things that seemed to be describing part of what I want to do. E.g.

The script piece should either

- Option A: Tell the browser that if the user is on a page which has the same address as a link in the menu it's href-address is, then it's submenu (ul li ul) or the menu (ul) where itself is contained in, should get "visiblity:visible".
- Option B:
  The script code says like "if the user clicks on an menu item (ul li), then it's submenu (ul li ul), if it has one, or if the menu-item that is being clicked is one of the submenus, then this submenu should become "visibility:visible". If the item that is clicked doesn't have a submenu, no submenu should be shown.

The HTML code must not have classes or other attributes directly anywhere between (nav) and (/nav) though.

Comment: Hey there! So... jQuery and PHP are quite different. jQuery is a JavaScript library and PHP is a web programming language.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you need a way to know if you are on a specific URL?

Comment: So, if we're on the `Team` page, should the parent `<li>` have a colour added, or a class-name? Don't give us 'options,' explain what you want/need. And please, *please*, show us your best efforts or evidence that you know what you're talking about: this is a site for *professional and enthusiast programmers*, not a free code-writing service.

Comment: oh I'm not professional.. sorry.. I thought this forum was for everyone.. :|

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS:

```
li ul {
   display: none;
}

li a:hover + ul {
   display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bxf6r33/

**[Edit]**

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/7bxf6r33/7/

Comment: yayy :D I will try that! but where do I put that Jquery??

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sure if i understand what you need,

you need when user go to some menu page it get the url and active that link on menu until the user is on that page right?

if is that,

i think something like that should work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $item = $('ul li a').filter(function(){
            return $(this).prop('href').indexOf(location.pathname) != -1;
        });
        $item.css('visibility','visible'); //or whatever ur using to active it.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working :(

I put it in the body like that:

"    <? 

    $(function(){
        $item = $('ul li a').filter(function(){
            return $(this).prop('href').indexOf(location.pathname) != -1;
        });
        $item.css('display','block'); //or whatever ur using to active it.
    });

    ?> "

so it became colorful... but also the first 3 lines got marked as red on the left...

Comment: Do you have this page landded on some server? Or fiddle? Becouse just imagination is not enough to figute it and make something who works. On stackoverflow we just give you a path or solve problems about code, you doesn't know code so its hard "help" you, you need the "thing" working.

Comment: And its a javascript, you should use like i edited now.